# Reading dates from Excel

Tags: r, excel, date

I am having two date(formatted as dd-mm-yyyy in excel) columns in my data in excel sheet.

```
Date Delivery   Date Collection
06-08-17    15-08-17
11-04-17    15-04-17
24-01-17    24-01-17
11-08-16    14-08-16
```

There are multiple issues.
Currently I am reading a subset of data(manually made of top 100 rows in another excel sheet.).

1. The dates in same format in excel are shown differently in R.
2. They all look like as in Data.Collection when I read the whole data set.

   `data <- read.xlsx("file.xlsx", sheetName='subset', startRow=1)`

The data output shown in R is

[image: Date formats in R].

I need them all to be shown as in Data.Delivery because I need to write the result back after analysis.

I am also trying to make it Date in R using

```
dates <- data$Date.Delivery
as.Date(dates, origin = "30-12-1899",format="%d-%m-%y")
```

Comment: Please use `read_excel()` from `readxl` package, as i observed this function enables auto detection of date columns and also read well

Comment: Tried. Same issue.

Comment: Please post sample input data from excel here

Comment: Date Delivery Date Collection
06-08-17 15-08-17
11-04-17 15-04-17
24-01-17 24-01-17
11-08-16 14-08-16

Comment: There is some issue with the amount of data. When I increase the data it starts taking the number format instead of date format.

Comment: origin should be '1899-12-30' in as.Date. it works: as.Date(dates, origin = "1899-12-30")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format `Date.Collection` as in `Data.Delivery` after reading your file, try

```
# see the str of your data
str(data)
# if Date.Collection is characher
data$Date.Collection <- as.numeric(data$Date.Collection)
# if Date.Collection is factor
data$Date.Collection <- as.numeric(levels(data$Date.Collection))[data$Date.Collection]
# conversion
data$Date.Collection <- as.Date(data$Date.Collection - 25569, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Comment: Error in data$Date.Collection - 25569 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: So you need to convert `data$Date.Collection` as numeric before. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

or you can read the file using "gdata"  or "XLConnect" packages to read the column as factor. 
then use ymd() from lubridate to convert it into date

`require(gdata)
data = read.xls (path, sheet = 1, header = TRUE)
data$Date.Collection <- ymd(data$Date.Collection)`